# ASMX Seems To Cache

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services

I have the following ASMX web service:

```
// removed for brevity //

namespace AtomicService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class Assets : WebService
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Validation));
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string CityCreate(string cityname, string state, string country,
            decimal timezoneoffset, decimal lat, decimal lon)
        {
            var response = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(cityname) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(country)))
            {
                response.Add("Response", "empty");
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
            }
            int tzid;
            int ctyid;
            try
            {
                tzid = AtomicCore.TimezoneObject.GetTimezoneIdByGMTOffset(timezoneoffset);
                var cty = AtomicCore.CountryObject.GetCountry(country);
                ctyid = cty.CountryId;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                response.Add("Response", "errordb");
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
            }
            if(AtomicCore.Validation.DoesCityAlreadyExistByLatLon(cityname, country, lat, lon))
            {
                response.Add("Response", "exists");
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
            }
            const string pattern = @"^(?<lat>(-?(90|(\d|[1-8]\d)(\.\d{1,6}){0,1})))\,{1}(?<long>(-?(180|(\d|\d\d|1[0-7]\d)(\.\d{1,6}){0,1})))$";
            var check = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
            bool valid = check.IsMatch(lat + "," + lon);
            if(valid == false)
            {
                response.Add("Response", "badlatlon");
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
            }
            BasicConfigurator.Configure();
            Log.Info("User created city; name:" + cityname + ", state:" + state + ", countryid:" + ctyid + ", timezoneid:" + tzid + ", lat:" + lat + ", lon:" + lon + "");

            //will return id of created city or 0.
            var result = AtomicCore.CityObject.CreateCity(cityname, state, ctyid, tzid, lat.ToString(), lon.ToString(), string.Empty);
            response.Add("Response", result > 0 ? "True" : "errordb");
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
}
```

This is called by a JQuery `$.ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://<%=Atomic.UI.Helpers.CurrentServer()%>/AtomicService/Assets.asmx/CityCreate",
                            data: "{'cityname':'" + $('#<%=litCity.ClientID%>').val() + "','state':'" + $('#<%=litState.ClientID%>').val() + "','country':'<%=Session["BusinessCountry"]%>','timezoneoffset':'" + $('#<%=litTimezone.ClientID%>').val() + "','lat':'" + $('#<%=litLat.ClientID%>').val() + "','lon':'" + $('#<%=litLng.ClientID%>').val() + "'}",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (msg) {
                                if (msg["d"].length > 0) {
                                    var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
                                    if (data.Response > 0) {
                                        //everything has been saved, ideally we
                                        //want to get the cityid and pass it back
                                        //to the map page so we can select it...
                                        alert('Hazzah!');
                                        $(this).dialog('close');
                                    } else {
                                        if(data.Response == 'errordb')
                                        {
                                            alert("db");
                                        }
                                        if(data.Response == 'exists')
                                        {
                                            alert("exists");
                                        }
                                        if(data.Response == 'badlatlon')
                                        {
                                            alert("badlatlon");
                                        }
                                        if(data.Response == 'empty')
                                        {
                                            alert("empty");
                                        }

                                        $('#serviceloader').hide();
                                        $('#<%=txtFindMyCity.ClientID%>:input').attr('disabled', false);
                                        $('#erroroccured').show('slow');
                                        $('#errortext').html("Unfortunately, we can't save this right now. We think this city may already exist within Atomic. Could you please check carefully and try again? If this is an obvious error, please contact us and we'll get you started.");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    $('#serviceloader').hide();
                                    $('#<%=txtFindMyCity.ClientID%>:input').attr('disabled', false);
                                    $('#erroroccured').show('slow');
                                    $('#errortext').html("Unfortunately, we can't save this right now. Our data service is not responding.  Could you perhaps try again in a few minutes? We're very sorry. Please contact us if this continues to happen.");
                                }
                            },
                            error: function (msg) {
                                $('#serviceloader').hide();
                                $('#<%=txtFindMyCity.ClientID%>:input').attr('disabled', false);
                                $('#erroroccured').show('slow');
                                $('#errortext').html("Unfortunately, we can't save this right now. Perhaps something has gone wrong with some of our data services. Why not try again? If the problem persists, please let us know and we'll get you started.");
                            }
                        });
```

And despite this, I always receive `{ "Response" : "False" }`.  I think this may be a cache problem - but I simply can't get the AJAX to run the service.  When I go directly to asset.asmx and invoke the service, the `CreateCity` method runs correctly.

This is a classic wood for the trees - I have looked at it too long and I'm giving up the will to live...

**Thus, the question is:** I'd like the `CreateCity` service work correctly, when called by `$.ajax`, and not receive a `{ "Response" : "False" }` response.  Can anyone provide any direction, help or assistance on how to achieve this with the code I have provided?  Please bear in mind that I believe that my service may be caching (hence the `{ "Response" : "False" }` response)...

Help, advice, flames and general comments welcomed...

Comment: If this was MVC I'd suggest you need an OutputCache attribute / @ directive - by default it assumes that the same request made with the same parameters should return the same result, unless you add metadata to change that. I don't know if those apply to ASMXs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually JSON serialize the response. This is automatically handled by script enabled services. Simply return a strongly typed object from your web method. Same for the input. Also you must ensure to properly URL encode the request parameters. So start by defining models:

```
public class City
{
    public string Cityname { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public decimal Timezoneoffset { get; set; }
    public decimal Lat { get; set; }
    public decimal Lon { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class Assets : WebService
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Validation));

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public Response CityCreate(City city)
    {
        var response = new Response();

        // ... process and populate the return message, 
        // set the IsSuccess boolean property which will
        // be used by the client (see next...)

        return response;
    }
}
```

and on the client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Assets.asmx/CityCreate") %>',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ 
        cityname: $('#<%=litCity.ClientID%>').val(),
        state: $('#<%=litState.ClientID%>').val(),
        country: '<%=Session["BusinessCountry"]%>',
        timezoneoffset: $('#<%=litTimezone.ClientID%>').val(),
        lat: $('#<%=litLat.ClientID%>').val(),
        lon: $('#<%=litLng.ClientID%>').val()
    }),
    success: function (result) {
        // result.d will represent the response so you could:
        if (result.d.IsSuccess) {
             ...
        } else {
             ...
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: excellent answer. I'm going to try this to see if this fixes the problems I'm having. Thanks very much ;)

Comment: absolutely awesome answer. It worked perfectly too :) Thanks! +1

Answer (score 0):

You can add `cache:false` to your `%.ajax` call to make sure it isn't being cached.  Have you popped a breakpoint on the service to double check what's being passed through from your jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the response David, I can't debug the .asmx for some reason either through VS2010, or by attaching the process. This may have something to do with another question I have open currently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611305/visual-studio-2010-debugging-entity-framework-project-throws-entityclient-provide ... Wood for the trees David, wood for the trees! :)

Comment: As an aside however, I have used Fiddler to see what is being passed to and fro, all seems completely normal. In-fact, I took on request and its values and invoked the service directly (/assets.asmx?op=CityCreate) and it worked...

Comment: Ahh I see.  Put a comment on that one also. :)

Comment: You don't need to use `cache: false` with POST requests as contrary to GET requests they should not be cached by browsers.

Comment: @Darin Ah yes of course.  In that case the stepping into the debugger advice still stands. :)